# Аутентификация на сайте с Python requests

Tags: python, веб-программирование, requests, urllib

Как авторизоваться на сайте с помощью requests. Нужно получить доступ к страницам, которые открыты только для авторизованных пользователей. HTTPBasicAuthentication и HTTPDigestAuthentication не работают, может я что не так сделал.
    `import requests
    from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
    url = 'https://domainName.com/#auth'
    r = requests.post(url=url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('log','pass'))`

В результате перенаправляет на главную страницу как неавторизованного пользователя.
 В общем как мне авторизоваться и что для этого использовать?

Comment: Для начала узнать точный механизм аутентификации, который используется на сайте

Comment: @andreymal Выдает такую ошибку 'Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение'. Думаю это из за каптчи, которую просит ввести сайт при входе. Как быть? Можно ли чтобы присылать каптчю мне чтобы я вводил ее вручную в скрипт, а он уже работал с введенным мной значением или еще что сделать?

Comment: Это означает, что вы подключаетесь куда-то вообще не туда, и там, куда вы подключаетесь, вообще нет никакого сервера. Капча ни при чём

Comment: @andreymal Прошу прощения, так вышло, что допустил ошибку в имени домена. Собственно я уже все перепробовал, ни в какую. Помогите кодом/советом как делать аутентифицированные запросы на этом сайте https://csgopositive.com/

Comment: Открывайте инструменты разработчика в браузере, смотрите в сети, что куда передаётся при входе, и повторяйте у себя в коде то же самое. Правда, с капчей вы в любом случае вряд ли справитесь

Comment: @andreymal не могу отследить какой запрос уходит после отправления формы и нажатия кнопки войти. После этого страница перезагружается и поле Network тоже. В итоге непонятно что за запрос был отправлен. Удалось только отследить logout, но какая от этого польза

Comment: Включите Непрерывные логи (Preserve log) там в настройках, и Network не будет перезагружаться

Comment: @andreymal Большое спасибо. В итоге нашел ajax запрос. Повторяю, отправляю s = requests.Session()
auth_data = dict(login='login',password='pass',action='auth')
s.headers = {Заголовки как в запросе}'}

r = s.post(url, data=auth_data)
Отвечает 200. Всё, казалось бы, хорошо, но далее сайт все равно видит меня как неавторизованного пользоваиетя. Делал так:
s.cookies = r.cookies Но не помогло. Я совсем в отчаянии